# Angular - как правильно подписаться на ng-model

Tags: javascript, angular

```
export interface Album
{
    AlbumId : number;
    Title : string;
    ArtistId : number;
    Artist : Artist;
}

export interface Artist
{
    ArtistId : number;
    Name : string;
}

  <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" [(ngModel)]="Album.Artist">
    <option selected>Выберите исполнителя</option>
    <option *ngFor="let album of albums"  [ngValue]="album.artist">{{ album.artist.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <p></p>
  <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" [(ngModel)]="Album">
    <option selected>Выберите альбом</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let album of albums" [ngValue]="album"> {{ album.title }}</option>
  </select>
```

Почему я не могу так сделать? 
У меня два селекта. Первый солект должен создать вложенный объект у объекта Album.
Второй селект должен дополнить объект Album.
На выходе в ngModel я должен получить объект Album с вложенным объектом Artist и отправить на сервер.

Я получаю ошибку в данном коде: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Artist' of undefined

Comment: причем тут [tag:c#]?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в том, что я не инициализировал свой объект.
Это делается следующим образом:   `Album  = {make: null};`